# bodymovin: converting .JSON to .SVG?

Tags: json, svg, bodymovin

My question:
Is there a way to convert .json to .SVG

My situation:
I have created animation adobe after effects, i then output a file using Bodymovin extension in after effects

I get the a .json file, and a html file that will show the animation but these don't seem to be places i can get a .svg, unless i can find a way to convert the .json which is why im here. The .svg file / json file both contain animation data. I want to use these animations on the web specifically the .svg file

What i have tried:
searching google results for an hour looking for solutions, none seem to exist thus far

Comment: https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-web/issues/47

Answer (score 0):

The [Lottie for Android](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android) library plays Bodymovin files.

Comment: aw sorry i have no coding experience, i was hoping for some kinda converter